# x64 mvc3 project with Oracle Data Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, 64-bit, odp.net

I'm using the Oracle Data Access(ODP.NET) in a mvc3 project. 
the odp.net has both x64 and x86 versions separately and i want to use the x64 version.

I set "Platform target" to x64 and add a reference to x64 version of odp.net, there is no problem to publish on iis server, but i can't run the project for develop and test, however Razor views display errors on c# statements.

How i can develop the project in x64 platform?

Comment: "but i can't run the project for develop and test, however Razor views display errors on c# statements." What errors are you getting?

Comment: for example displays a red line under "@model List<Project.Model.Plan>", and on mouse over displays "Could not load file or assembly 'project' or one of dependencies. an attempts was to load a program wit an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the immediate problem is forcing your platform target to x64.  The asp.net development server is 32 bit.  Either leave it as "Any CPU" or run a 64 bit dev server (either the local IIS server or compile [cassinidev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) as 64 bit).  If you do leave it as any cpu so you can continue to use the out of the box dev server, you'll get the same error with the 64 bit version of oracle.dataaccess.dll for the exact same reason.

I install the 32 bit version on my machine (i also install the 64 bit version but I mention that only to note that they run fine side by side).  The reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll does not include bit-ness, only version.  So as long as you have the same version (or later with publisher policies) of the 64 bit flavor on the server, everything will run fine once you deploy.